# How i can use variable of one function to another function in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-views

I'm writing a program to edit student details(not as a admin). I have to different def's that hold the variables that contain the username. in first one i am trying to get username and in another def that actually applying the edit functionality. but it needs the variable that contains the username. How can I call the variables from the first one? Sorry for the weird wording. I don't know how else to say it :P Thanks!

```
def get_username(request):
    #the code to open up a input fields that gets the username
    username = input

def edit_student(request):
    #the code to open up a pre populated form with the instance of the same student which i get from get_username()
```

Comment: get_username is a django view or  just function describe details in function

Comment: this is django view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple you have just to make a call to the first function from the second function:

first function:

```
def get_username():
    username = input
    return username
```

second function:

```
def edit_student():
    username = get_username()
```

Comment: no this is django function views. this is not working in that.

Answer (score 2):

Dont know why one answer is here marked this as correct answer any way if you want is sharing input with other view, you can use session.

```
def get_username(request):
    #the code to open up a input fields that gets the username
    username = input
    # after getting username , you can store the value in current session
    request.session['username'] = input

def edit_student(request):
    # someway edit_student view is reached, here you can get username
    username = request.session['username']
    # use this username to perform operations
```

NOTE: if you meant adding a user login functionality check [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/)

Comment: This answer will be here for someone who know what is django view and what is plain functions

Answer (score 1):

You might want to pass the variables into the view using the url. Is usually done like this:

```
def edit_student(request, id):

    username = get_username(id)
```

And the url to edit the student will be:

localhost:8000/student/67

To know more check the [docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#specifying-defaults-for-view-arguments)